# Use of forEach to only one return data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to get user email, so I "select" from users some username.
This will return only one data because users cannot repeat usernames.

```
firebase.database().ref('/users/').orderByChild('user').equalTo(username).once('value').then(snapshot => {          
            snapshot.forEach((subChild) => {
                var value = subChild.val();     
                value = value.email;
                console.log(value); // the email.
            });
```

forEach is a loop, so I was thinking, do I need to use forEach even knowing I only will have 1 result?

Answer (score 2):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if *you* can guarantee that there is only a single result, the API cannot know this and the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

So yes, the loop is needed, even when there's only one result.